# How can I open and close port on Windows7

Tags: port

i have few questions..
I am using Windows7 and I just wanted to open telnet port.
So, I did check telnet client box and open telnet port(23) on the firewall 
and I did open command box and typing netstat-an but, I could't find the telnet port
What is the wrong with it??
Did I wrong to do? 
help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allowed services/daemon to listen (receive TCP packages) on this port. But there is no service running, so netstat-an got nothing to show.

Comment: Oh, Thanks so much.. The problem was SO simple.. Thanks :)